# Targeting elements of an a-tag with Nokogiri when classes dont work

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to build a scraper and I would need some help with the following:

I would like to grab a bunch of data from an a-tag and some divs/spans nested in the same div. 
My code look like this:

```
  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(website))

  page.search('.company').each { |e| companies << e.text.strip }
  page.search('.jobtitle').each { |e| jobtitles << e.text.strip }
  page.search('.location').each { |e| locations << e.text.strip }

  page.xpath('//a[@class="turnstileLink"]').map{ |e| links << e['href'] }
```

For the first three (company, title and location) I get either 16 or 15 results, but for the last search my array only contains 10 elements. Weirdly its they also dont match the first 10 of one of the other arrays, but rather start matching somewhere around the 3rd or 4th element of one of the other arrays.

The html of a typical card that I would like to target is here:

```
<div class="row result clickcard" id="pj_81c3e09223cbc6b3" data-jk="81c3e09223cbc6b3" data-advn="4563763653116462" data-tu="">
        <a target="_blank" id="sja1" data-tn-element="jobTitle" class="jobtitle turnstileLink" href="/pagead/clk?mo=r&amp;ad=-6NYlbfkN0DhDTzlYIMy8YIuVE6IrMC_kH05KGZgoAT6LTrcTn8STrwXoiuruouegXiAvJy4qud6xIecRibm3b0Q5eOBkpCiV3R04sAyQbvP7gt6NKZVpCRp32eFzXudmk-TIABX3xEZGo90a47Vz9OofqZaLDh37545RNQ3sFjM6VzWNEWwKf_YoXxeGKcAICj9AADyBuYAY7p9UIUxoox7J5U9gO8Zo2dvRW-i5FJtaUr49Vjsl04W0Jp-CN2azbfp6rrfT6RYFbJ_YAc2iI-L37eeygDtI4KXQwv_elrV8ZLEKo9rkcfEzbE129kX7JKeEq5wJ1dj7GJ4ONH1lIPJQd1gJLoqNYJVQlLTKJiBP72Z0RBmgfZQ-69U8AoEyMT6pytz6iqykLCnO-SxClmvFPJsNV96oBGzpMWtWQeVgGQ49jZfBBRq9Ubw7N73iEjCv6oQ70hcW1P4d8DYK0pCI7vu2KfUh0P9vx8AKC6wY2QoAZeeP4OiBIJ8ikKSIUYJTbe3UwKcLYP7r_3_rx1gY_JO1ReG21ctCxfqGH9DnqTSjz3SYCMZ2ZekooXa&amp;vjs=3&amp;p=1&amp;sk=&amp;fvj=1" title="Private Care Jobs With Elder - Immediate Start - £550 to £750 pw" rel="noopener nofollow" onmousedown="sjomd('sja1'); clk('sja1');" onclick="setRefineByCookie([]); sjoc('sja1',0); convCtr('SJ')">Private Care Jobs With Elder - Immediate Start - £550 to £75...</a>

        <br>
        <div class="sjcl">
        <span class="company">
Elder</span>

<span class="location">London</span>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td class="snip">
                    <span class="summary">
                        Pass a full DBS check or have a valid check already. Access to the internet and a smartphone. At Elder, we’re looking for caring individuals to join our...</span>
                </td></tr></tbody></table>
            </div>

            <div class="sjCapt">
                <div class="result-link-bar-container">
                        <div class="result-link-bar"><span class=" sponsoredGray ">Sponsored</span> - <span id="tt_set_10" class="tt_set"><a id="sj_81c3e09223cbc6b3" href="#" class="sl resultLink save-job-link " onclick="changeJobState('81c3e09223cbc6b3', 'save', 'linkbar', true, ''); return false;" title="Save this job to my.indeed">save job</a></span><div id="editsaved2_81c3e09223cbc6b3" class="edit_note_content" style="display:none;"></div><script>if (!window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']) {window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3'] = {};}window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['showSource'] = false; window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['source'] = "Indeed"; window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['loggedIn'] = false; window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['showMyJobsLinks'] = false;window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['undoAction'] = "unsave";window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['jobKey'] = "81c3e09223cbc6b3"; window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['myIndeedAvailable'] = true; window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['showMoreActionsLink'] = window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['showMoreActionsLink'] || false; window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['resultNumber'] = 10; window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['jobStateChangedToSaved'] = false; window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['searchState'] = "l=London&amp;start=20"; window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['basicPermaLink'] = "https://www.indeed.co.uk"; window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['saveJobFailed'] = false; window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['removeJobFailed'] = false; window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['requestPending'] = false; window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['notesEnabled'] = false; window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['currentPage'] = "serp"; window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['sponsored'] = true;window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['showSponsor'] = true;window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['reportJobButtonEnabled'] = false; window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['showMyJobsHired'] = false; window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['showSaveForSponsored'] = true; window['sj_result_81c3e09223cbc6b3']['showJobAge'] = true;</script></div></div>
                    <div class="tab-container">
                        <div class="sign-in-container result-tab"></div>
                        <div class="tellafriend-container result-tab email_job_content"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

All cards have the same class ".clickcard" and all the relevant links have the class ".turnstileLink" but I cant seem to get consistent results when i try to page.search or page.xpath them, without having a problem matching up the data from all the different arrays correctly, besides the different number of elements I get returned.

So my question is: If I want to scrape the company name, location, job title, the url to that page and possibly another value, how would I best go about this?

I would appreciate any feedback!

Comment: For the `xpath` statement, use `each` instead of `map`

Comment: tried that and it still leaves me 3 links short (12 links when there should be 15). I also double checked and all cards have an a tag with the .turnstileLink class.

Comment: Using the html you posted, for the first three I get one result; and for the last one I get no results.

Comment: oh, i apologise. the website is www.indeed.co.uk, the results page after you enter a search. as its a large site the html is large and messy which is why i just selected a card instead of a larger html. 
as to the last part of the code: I do get results, as i find 12 elements in my array...

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

The contains() expression needs to be more complex:

```
contains(
      concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),
      ' turnstileLink '  
)
```

to prevent classes like `turnstileLinkerCar` from matching.  It's such a hassle that I would use `doc.css()` with a css selector like `a.turnstileLink`, which takes care of matching exactly the specified class name in a string that may have multiple class names.

---

Try:

```
doc.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "turnstileLink")]').each{ |e| links << e['href'] }
```

Or:

```
doc.css('a.turnstileLink').each{ |e| links << e['href'] }
```

Here's the problem:

```
require 'nokogiri'

my_html = %q{
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="aaa" class="c1">A link</a>
    <a href="bbb" class="c1 c2">B link</a>
    <a href="ccc" class="c2 c1">C link</a>
    <a href="ddd" class="c2 c1 c3">D link</a>
  </body>
</html>
}

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(my_html)
links = doc.xpath('//a[@class="c1"]').map{ |e| e["href"] }

p links

--output:--
["aaa"]
```

The class of the bbb link is `"c1 c2"` which is not equal to `"c1"`.

**Response to comment**:

```
require 'nokogiri'

my_html = %q{
<html>
  <body>
  <div class="x">
    <a href="aaa" class="c1">A link</a>
    <a href="bbb" class="c1 c2">B link</a>
    <a href="ccc" class="c2 c1">C link</a>
    <div>
      <a href="ddd" class="c2 c1 c3">D link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="y">
    <a href="yyy" class="c1">Y link</a>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
}

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(my_html)
links = doc.css('a.c1').map{ |e| e["href"] }
p links

--output:--
["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "yyy"]
```

But:

```
links = doc.css('div.x  a.c1').map{ |e| e["href"] }
p links
--output:--
["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]
```

The same thing with xpaths:

```
links = doc.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "x")]//a[contains(@class, "c1")]').map{ |e| e["href"] }
plinks

--output:--
["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]
```

Comment: for some reason that gets me 19 and 22 elements. my guess is that it might be pulling in otherlinks somehow? 
website is www.indeed.co.uk, after the search its the results page

Comment: I don't know what you did, but you need to start your search with the .clickcard `div`, then search that div for the a tags.

Comment: with reference to your edit that makes sense. so would this work:
first search all the c1s
   links = doc.xpath('//a[@class="c1"]').map{ |e| e["href"] }
then searching for c1 c2?
   links = doc.xpath('//a[@class="c1 c2"]').map{ |e| e["href"] }

Comment: Why didn't you use contains()? That was the whole point of my answer.  See the new example I posted.  Note that if you use `doc.css()` you don't have to worry about contains()--the css does that for you.

Comment: @Lemontree, Actually, the contains() expression needs to be even more complex because the class "c1xxx" contains "c1".  See my answer for the contains() expression needed to find classes like "c1" but not "c1xxx".

Comment: sorry for being so slow. I just tried this:
 links = page.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "clickcard")]//a[contains(@class, "turnstileLink")]').map{ |e| e["href"] }
this gives me an empty array now.

Comment: @Lemontree, You can run my example and see that it works fine.

Comment: Ok thank you for your advice. going by this my targeting is likely too broad. ill give this a try. Thanks again!

Comment: @Lemontree, I don't get an empty array using your xpath on the html you posted--but see the edit at the beginning of my post.  If I were you, I would use `doc.css()`--the "path" is so much simpler.